# Since last patch, unable to open excel documents and word documents can only be opened by dropdown

Tags: 2010, excel, excel-services, office-integration, word

We performed updates to the SharePoint Portal, SharePoint Foundation, Office Sharepoint Server, Excel Services Component, and Word Server on 03/16/2014.  Since then, we are unable to open Excel documents within the browser.

We are greeted with the error:

> Unable to process the request.  Wait a few minutes and try performing
>   this operation again.

We are also unable to open and edit word documents by simply clicking on them.  Now we have to select the dropdown and request to edit the document (even this doesn't work for some).

Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows of a solution?  Is there an issue with the latest patch?

Comment: Have you looked in the ULS logs for more detailed information? That is the first step for your troubleshooting and will give more information than the normally vague error greeting above.

Comment: Which build did you update to?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve this issue by resetting IIS.